# Want to select the  minimums of the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that returns the following

```
TABLE People


Name    id

Paco    18
Paco    32
Pedro   41
Pedro   86
```

I want to get the following with a query

```
Name    id

Paco    18
Pedro   41
```

Basically i want the minimum id of the repeated occurence?

Comment: what is the sql query which gave you the first result?

Comment: Lets supoose thats the table..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, MIN(id) AS 'id'
FROM People
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:

```
select name, min(id) as id
from people
group by name
```